# How to $.trim a contenteditiable div on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to trim a contenteditable div upon keypress, however nothing seems to be working.

HTML

```
<div class="datacollection NoFirstInputSpace" placeholder="____________" contenteditable</div>

$(document).on('keypress', '.NoFirstInputSpace', function(e) {

    var str = $(this).text();
    $.trim(str);
    var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if (code === 32 && (e.target.selectionStart === 0 || getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(e.target) === 0)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

});
```

The keypress works correctly, it prevents the suer from entering a space as the first character of the contenteditable div. However the problem is if the end user types a string then highlights it and then presses the space bar it will replace the string with a space, which i cant have a space as the first character

Comment: Any errors in dev console?

Comment: No there are not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind the `keyup` event instead and check when pressed key is <kbd>Space</kbd>.

If true, you trim the empty spaces and set `.text()` = to empty.

Also, `keyCode` is deprecated. Use `key`.

See [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key).

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.NoFirstInputSpace', function(e) {
  if (e.key == ' ') {
    var text = $.trim($(this).text());
    if (text == '') {
      $(this).text('');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.NoFirstInputSpace {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="datacollection NoFirstInputSpace" placeholder="____________" contenteditable></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! @doutriforce , classic example of me over complicating things for no reason!

Comment: No problem, @Charles. I also have a bit of experience in complicating things sometimes. Lol.